# matlab count rows contain same elements in matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, count, row

I have a matrix like this:

```
A = [1   2   3
     3   4   5
     6   8   7
     7   9   11
     12  13  15
     17  18  19
];
```

How can I count rows that contain same element? In this case it  will result 4: row 1 and row 2 contain 3; row 3 and row 4 contain 7.
thank you...

Comment: No, the conditions I have doesn't allow that..

Comment: If you can't have duplicates on a single line as you say, and each row may only have duplicate values with one other row: `2*(numel(A) - numel(unique(A)))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = [1   2   3
 3   4   5
 6   8   7
 7   9   11
 12  13  15
 17  18  19
]
B = unique(A)
L = length(B)
Z = []
R = 0
for t=1:L
  [C,D] = ismember(A,B(t))
  SS = sum(sum(D))
  if(SS>1)
     Z(end+1) = B(t)
     R = R + nnz(sum(D,2))
  end
end
```

at the end of this, the vector Z will contain all repeated values
R will give you the total number of repeated rows

This has been done quite roughly. but with a bit of effort you can improve this code by eliminating the loop somehow....

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey Phoenix small advice: when you use `sum(sum(2Dmatrix))` you can also use `sum(2Dmatrix(:))`. It's a more general way to sum a matrix along all dimensions.

Comment: @obchardon Thanks very much! I never thought of that trick. It will make my future codes a lil bit better! Especially when you are not sure of the dimension of the matrix

Answer (score 1):

One solution, not really optimized but it will work fine if your matrix is not that big.

```
A = [1   2   3;
     3   4   5;
     6   8   7;
     7   9   11;
     12  13  15;
     17  18  19];

for ii = 1:size(A,1)
    B = A;
    B(ii,:) = [];
    ind(ii,:) = sum(ismember(unique(A(ii,:)),unique(B)))>0; %check if there is a common value for the row ii.
end

nbrrow = sum(ind) %number of row that contain a similar value.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast way that is also robust for a value repeating in more than 2 rows (but not in the same row):

```
[~,~,ci] = unique(A);
u = accumarray(ci,1);
row_count = sum(u(u>1))
```